# AttributeError: module 'tf_util' has no attribute 'conv2d'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

When I run pointnet code on my own dataset, I got a problem on 'conv2d'.  My tensorflow version: 1.8.0, cudatoolkit 9.0  cudnn   7.6.5. Could anyone help me? is that a version problem?

```
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:521: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:522: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/yanz/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 74, in main
    pred = get_model(pointclouds_pl, is_training=is_training_pl, bn_decay=bn_decay)
  File "/home/yanz/PointNet/model.py", line 30, in get_model
    net = tf_util.conv2d(input_image, 64, [1, 4], padding='VALID', stride=[1, 1],
AttributeError: module 'tf_util' has no attribute 'conv2d'
```

Comment: the python version:3.6

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add relevant code, also kindly do not spam irrelevant tags; there is nothing about `numpy`. (edited)

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The author of PointNet custom made the function, and it can be found at pointnet/utils/tf_util.py
Link:
https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/utils/tf_util.py